# Oracle: Sum function "not a single-group group function error"

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

I have an **ORDER_LINE** table in which I am trying to multiply the **NUM_ORDERED** of parts by the **QUOTED_PRICE** for each **ORDER_NUM**. I am adding **SUM()** function to group by **ORDER_NUM**, because if I didn't, there would be multiple entries for the same order.

ORDER_LINE Table:

```
ORDER_NUM   PART_NUM    NUM_ORDERED     QUOTED_PRICE
21608       AT94        11              21.95
21610       DR93        1               495
21610       DW11        1               399.99
21613       KL62        4               329.95
21614       KT03        2               595
21617       BV06        2               794.95
21617       CD52        4               150
21619       DR93        1               495
21623       KV29        2               1290
```

Query:

```
SELECT ORDER_NUM, SUM(NUM_ORDERED * QUOTED_PRICE) AS TOTAL_AMOUNT
FROM
ORDER_LINE
ORDER BY ORDER_NUM;
```

Expected Result:

```
ORDER_NUM   TOTAL_AMOUNT
21608       241.45
21610       894.99
21613       1319.8
21614       1190
21617       2189.9
21619       495
21623       2580
```

> Error ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

If I remove the Sum function I get the following result:

```
SELECT ORDER_NUM, (NUM_ORDERED * QUOTED_PRICE) AS TOTAL_AMOUNT
FROM
ORDER_LINE
ORDER BY ORDER_NUM;

ORDER_NUM   TOTAL_AMOUNT
21608       241.45
21610       495
21610       399.99
21613       1319.8
21614       1190
21617       1589.9
21617       600
21619       495
21623       2580
```

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm missing something, you just need to add `GROUP BY ORDER_NUM`, don't you?

```
SELECT ORDER_NUM, SUM(NUM_ORDERED * QUOTED_PRICE) AS TOTAL_AMOUNT
FROM
ORDER_LINE
GROUP BY ORDER_NUM
ORDER BY ORDER_NUM;
```